# Bootstrap nav-collapse links not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, hyperlink

I'm having a problem regarding dropdown menus not working on mobile devices that i've been struggling with for a week. I've taken a copy of the current example from the bootstrap site, modified it a bit and during the test i noticed it didn't work as expected. (same goes for the original example(http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html), where i only add a link to for instance google) - why this behaviour?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Dropdown test</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Links<span class="caret"></span></a>       
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="blank">Google (opens in new window)</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.bing.com" target="blank">Bing (opens in new window)</a></li>
              <li><a class="linkcheck" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
              <li><a class="linkcheck" href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li><!-- .dropdown -->
        </ul><!-- .nav -->
      </div><!-- .nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- .container -->
  </div><!-- .navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- .navbar -->
```

Bootstrap is new to me, and i can't find any documentation on nav-collapse, where can i find this? 
And do i really have to do a click event, then window.open(url)? (or does onclick behave different on a mobile device?)

Here's my online example: http://test-web.dk/sandbox/bootstrap/

Edit: 
Found a solution:

```
$('.linkcheck', this).click(function(){
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  alert("link clicked:" + url);
  if(url.match(/^http:/)) {
    window.location.href = url;
  }
});

// fix by RobDodson: github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4550
// Kills regular links in browsers though, but they will be redirected by linkcheck above
$('.dropdown a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
      $(this).siblings('.dropdown-backdrop').off().remove();
    }
  }, this), 0);
});
```

Still, a real bootstrap solution would be nice to known, rather than a hack :-) So if anybody has a suggestion, please post it.

Comment: Another easy fix: https://github.com/Bitergia/bootstrap/commit/25e8eeb

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using the most up to date jQuery.

I was having the same problem with the Bootstrap theme for Drupal, but solved this problem by changing the settings in jQuery Update to the most up to date!